# To make or not to make...python-nautilus a dependency?

Tags: nautilus, application-development, python, dependencies

That is the question!

---

Okay, all silliness aside, I really am forced to make a difficult decision here. My application is written in C++ and allows other scripts to invoke methods via XML-RPC. One of these scripts is a Nautilus extension written in Python. The extension is packaged with the rest of the application and copied to the appropriate place when installed (`/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions`).

Now the problem is that the Nautilus extension requires the [python-nautilus [image: Install python-nautilus]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-nautilus) package to be installed to be operational. So therefore I have three options:

- **Make the `python-nautilus` package a dependency.** This option will ensure that anyone who installs my package will be able to use the Nautilus extension. However, this option will not be attractive to XFCE or KDE users - a ton of `python-nautilus`'s dependencies will be installed on their machines and take up a lot of space - even if they never use Nautilus.
- **Put the `python-nautilus` package in the `suggests:` or `recommends:` field.** This option provides the end-user with a way to avoid installing the `python-nautilus` package (by providing the `--no-install-suggests` or `--no-install-recommends` argument to `apt-get`). However, this won't work when the user installs the package in the Software Center. (I always get mixed up as to which of those two fields are installed by default.)
- **Prompt the user when the application is installed or first launched.** This option is more complicated than the others but offers the best compromise between making it easy for the user to install `python-nautilus` (without going into a technical explanation) and not installing it when the user doesn't need it (or want it). I guess the best way to implement this is a simple prompt that invokes `apt-get` if the user would like the package installed.
- **Don't install the package at all.** This option ensures that *nobody* has `python-nautilus` installed on their machine unless they want it. However, this also means that my Nautilus extension will simply not run on the end-user's machine unless they manually install the package.

Which of these options seems the best choice? Have I missed any pros and cons for each of the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *a ton of python-nautilus's dependencies will be installed on their machines*

You know, I thought "let's take a look at whether this is an African or a European ton," and...

```
python-nautilus
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libnautilus-extension1a
  Depends: libpython2.7
  Depends: python-gi
  Depends: gir1.2-nautilus-3.0
```

- In **XFCE/Xubuntu** and **LXDE/Lubuntu**:

  ```
  The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 python-nautilus
  0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
  Need to get 25.2 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 410 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  ```
- In **KDE/Kubuntu**:

  ```
  The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libnautilus-extension1a
  Suggested packages:
  librsvg2-common gvfs
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libnautilus-extension1a python-nautilus
  0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
  Need to get 2,835 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 8,672 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  ```

So, almost nothing at all for XFCE/LXDE, and 8.5MB--not the end of the world--for KDE.

I recommend making `python-nautilus` a...recommends. Which will be installed as a dependency by `apt-get`/Synaptic/Software Center unless told otherwise.

For the few that refuse to use `apt-get` but know the difference between recommends and dependencies, and don't want recommends, the `APT::Install-Recommends=0` property will be honored by both Synaptic and Software Center. The property can be set graphically from Synaptic preferences, or manually via `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how important that Nautilus extension is for your application:

- If your application is not really usable without it make `python-nautilus` a dependency
- If your application is usable without it but lacks some important features make it a `Recommends`
- If it's just nice to have make it a `Suggests`

Instead of using `Suggests` I would prefer to make the extension a package of its own. That way it is easier for a user to find out what he needs to install if he want to use the extension.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be a separate package because 1) I couldn't submit it to MyApps and 2) it therefore wouldn't be eligible for the contest.

Comment: Also, if I add it to `Suggests:`, will the suggestion show up anywhere in the Software Center?

Comment: If it is for the contest I'd ask if there are any rules for such cases. There seems to be a way to show "extensions" in software center but I don't know how it works.